# Universe database attaching to Universe database server

Tags: universe

I was sent a UniVerse database.  I installed a trial version of the UniVerse database server from Rocket Software.  However, I cannot find any walkthroughs on how to use the UniVerse database server software.  Given the UniVerse Shell that was installed, I'm assuming this is all command line.  I've tried going through the HELP menu, but it is severely lacking and horribly formatted.  Has anyone run into this problem?  I'm looking to attach the database file and get any schema information I can from it.

Answer (score 0):

A universe "database" is kind of an abstraction of a file system, at least in my experience using AIX/Linux.  If you have universe installed and running there really isn't any kind of attaching you need to do. Change the directory to where you extracted the db and then execute the command /your/path/to/bin/uv and it will launch the shell.

Also it sounds like you are experiencing some terminal emulation issues, so you might want to find a terminal emulator that gives you the ability to switch emulations on the fly. I use Dynamic Connect which was delivered with the product back when it still belonged to IBM. I am not sure about open source alternatives as I am lazy and DC is already paid for. If you get into a screen that is all dorked up try switching the emulation around. Most of what I work in is a combination of addsvp, regent, and vt100. You will need to redraw the screen when you change it to see if it works and I can't really give you a solid strategy of how to do that consistently outside of general button mashing.

Of course if you have no experience with Universe, or at least another Pick variant, you are likely going to have any idea what you are doing.

I would recommend checking out Manny Neira's tutorials on Universe. It is probably the most easy to follow tutorial I have found on the subject in the Internet era.

http://www.mannyneira.com/universe/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the sending agent the following questions:

1. By universe database is this a full version of universe?
2. Is it a single Account?
3. Is it a single file?
4. What soft of backup, am assuming here, was done - simply copied files, an account backup (you can then restore), or other mechanism.

If you have got into Universe you are at what is call TCL (terminal control) and can execute universe commands, e.g.

LIST VOC

LIST UV.ACCOUNT

Please note Universe is not a relational database like say MS Access, MySQL etc, its what is call a multi value database. If you have not used one of the mv databases then you could be in a spot of bother as things are going to be pretty alien for you.